# Set environment variable GCOV_PREFIX (with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc)

Tags: gcc, code-coverage

All

We are trying to use arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc 4.2.1.

We compile application with flags "-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage".

Then run on the board.

For the source file at location, /home/user/TestApp/HelloApp/,  .gcda 
files are generated correctly in the folder 
/home/user/TestApp/HelloApp/ on the target.

Setting environment flags GCOV_PREFIX and GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP do not 
seem any effect in relocating the .gcda files.

For example, on setting GCOV_PREFIX=/temp/app/ and 
GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP=4, there is no change at all.

How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution: You need to set the environment flags `GCOV_PREFIX` and `GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP` on board instead of my compile pc.